# Politely asking to stay at someone's home? お邪魔させてもらう、泊めてもらう、or 滞在させてもらう?

Tags: set-phrases, politeness, phrase-requests, questions, formality

Which of the following is the most polite?  Is any of them incorrect?  Is there a more standard way to ask someone if you could stay with them while in town?

~  8日から9日まで、あなたのお宅にお邪魔させてもらえませんか。

~  8日から9日まで、お宅に泊めてもらえませんか。

~  8日から9日まで、あなたのお宅に滞在させてもらえませんか。

Is 「あなたの」 unnecessary?

Is 「あなたのお宅にお邪魔させてもらえませんか。」 ambiguous?  In other words, would the reader clearly understand it is a request to stay overnight rather than to drop by?

Can 「お宅」 be used to refer to a place of residence when it is not a personally-owned house, such as a share house apartment シェアハウスのマンション?

Also, can 「8日から9日まで、」be shrunk down to 「8〜9日に」?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- All of them are syntactically correct, but they are semantically strange as explained below. Depending on the situation, `もらう` may not be polite enough. `いただく` will be even more polite.
- In the second one, `泊める` is just about the night, so it is unnatural to mention  `8日から9日まで`, which means the whole two days (unless you are talking about both  nights of `8日` and `9日`, in which case it would be better to say `8日と9日の晩`). If you intend to stay only on the night of `8日`, then `8日の晩` would be better.
- The third one is unnatural because `滞在` implies much longer span than a day or two.
- `あなたの` is unnecessary.
- `あなたのお宅にお邪魔させてもらえませんか。` does not mean to stay over night (unless, for example, the context is about lovers, and you have a shared knowledge that visiting implies staying over night).
- It is not impossible for `お宅` to refer to share house apartment, but `お家{うち}` would be better.
- The following is not just for Japanese: The expression `... から ... まで` or `from ... to ...` is usually used when you are talking about a range of more than two things; it is unnatural here. You should use `... と ...` or `... and ...`.

Considering this, a better expression is:

> 8日の晩、おうちに泊めていただけませんか。